# Linq-to-SQL: arithmetic operation on consecutive elements

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

For example, I have a table:

```
Date      |Value
----------|-----
2015/10/01|5
2015/09/01|8
2015/08/01|10
```

Is there any way using Linq-to-SQL to get a new sequence which will be an arithmetic operation between consecutive elements in the previously ordered set (for example, `i.Value - (i-1).Value`)? It must be executed on SQL Server 2008 side, not application side.

For example `dataContext.GetTable<X>().OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Something(.......).ToArray();` should return `3, 2`.

Is it possible?

Comment: possibly you need use [Aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This operation is most commonly referred to as a fold, but got named `Aggregate` in the LINQ implementation.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot also known as `reduce` :-)

Comment: @Grundy, possibly, but I can't figure how I can use it. `Aggregate` returns single value. Using `Aggregate` I can subtract all table rows, but not pairs. Am I correct?

Comment: @Grundy Is Aggregate capable of performing operations on *consecutive* records, ignoring all other previous records?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos you can filter what record you need and aggregate then

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var q = (
         from i in Items
         orderby i.ItemDate descending
         let prev = Items.Where(x => x.ItemDate < i.ItemDate).FirstOrDefault()
         select new { Value = i.ItemValue - (prev == null ? 0 : prev.ItemValue) }
        ).ToArray();
```

**EDIT:**

If you slightly modify the above linq query to:

```
var q = (from i in Items
         orderby i.ItemDate descending
         let prev = Items.Where(x => x.ItemDate < i.ItemDate).FirstOrDefault()
         select new { Value = (int?)i.ItemValue - prev.ItemValue }
        ).ToArray();
```

then you get the following TSQL query sent to the database:

```
SELECT ([t0].[ItemValue]) - ((SELECT [t2].[ItemValue]
                              FROM (SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[ItemValue]
                                    FROM [Items] AS [t1]
                                    WHERE [t1].[ItemDate] < [t0].[ItemDate]) AS [t2]
                              )) AS [Value]
FROM [Items] AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[ItemDate] DESC
```

My guess now is if you place an index on `ItemDate` field this shouldn't perform too bad.

Comment: Will `Items.Where(x => x.ItemDate < i.ItemDate).FirstOrDefault()` run zillions of times or SQL Server optimizes it to something like `JOIN`?

Comment: Well, this is a good question. You can try it out and see what sql is being generated. Unfortunatley there is no such thing as a `LAG` operator in Linq

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't let SQL do this, it would create an inefficient SQL query (I think).

I could create a stored procedure, but if the amount of data is not too big I can also use Linq to objects:

```
List<x> items=dataContext.GetTable<X>().OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).ToList();//Bring data to memory

var res = items.Skip(1).Zip(items, (cur, prev) => cur.Value - prev.Value);
```

At the end, I might use a foreach for readability